# How to display a multi-line output from cmd in c#

Tags: c#, cmd, output

I need my c# program to run a cmd query to show all sql services and then display them in a message box. In the situation I will be running this in, there will frequently be more than one and the names may be different each time.

"Wmic service where (PathName like '%Binn\sqlservr%') get caption, name" displays the information I need but there are multiple lines returned. the WriteNote() method is one that writes the information to a textbox in the program.

I have tried everything I can find on Google and nothing seems to be working.

```
    private void DoListSQLServices()
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Process process = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
        System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo();
        //startInfo.WindowStyle = System.Diagnostics.ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
        startInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
        startInfo.Arguments = "Wmic service where (PathName like '%Binn\\sqlservr%') get caption, name";
        process.StartInfo = startInfo;
        startInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        startInfo.UseShellExecute = false; 
        process.Start();
        string output = process.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();

          this.WriteNote(output);
        process.WaitForExit();             
    }
```

When I run this code I get this:

Microsoft Windows [Version 6.1.7601]
Copyright (c) 2009 Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

{file location of project}\bin\Debug>

and a pbd file is put in the debug folder.

What I want is for it to show the caption and name of the SQL services like if you run that command through cmd manually. Ultimately the user will type one of them in for the program to restart them but I would rather have the program display the list than have the user go to Services in windows and search for them manually.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I get the same thing if I use TextBox1.Text = output; instead of WriteNote(output);

Comment: you need to waitforexit before trying to get the output

Comment: but, why don't you just use https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.serviceprocess.servicecontroller.getservices?view=netframework-4.7.2

Comment: So you are starting CMD.Exe and capturing it's output. But then (incorrectly) telling it to start another program. So, lose cmd.exe altogether (and in future see `cmd /?` on how to use it anyway. Exec wmic. But C# can do everything plus a bit more than wmic. WMIC is a command line interface to WMI which is what programmers use.

Comment: Thanks for the responses! @Noodles how would I do this using WMI? I haven’t been able to locate anything that works on that either

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/cimwin32prov/win32-service

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned by Noodles in the comments, it's much better to do this via the WMI support in .NET.  One of the fairly direct methods for this is to use the `ManagementObjectSearcher` class to execute an `ObjectQuery` against the WMI data.

Create a new console application.  Add a reference for the `System.Management` assembly to and add `using System.Management;` to the top of your `program.cs` file.

Now add the following code:

```
static void Main()
{
    // Create a scope (connection to WMI)
    var scope = new ManagementScope(@"\\localhost\root\cimv2");

    // Create query
    var query = new ObjectQuery(@"SELECT Name,Caption FROM Win32_Service WHERE PathName like '%Binn\\sqlserv%'");

    // Create a search to run the query against the scope
    using (var search = new ManagementObjectSearcher(scope, query))
    {
        // Iterate through the query results
        foreach (var item in search.Get())
        {
            // get values, all strings in this case
            string name = (string)item["Name"];
            string caption = (string)item["Caption"];
            Console.WriteLine("{0}\t{1}", name, caption);
        }
    }
}
```

Note that the `ObjectQuery` query syntax is a little different to the WMIC syntax.  It's called WQL (WMI Query Language) and is heavily modelled on SQL.

Hopefully you can adapt the above for your own use fairly easily.  Just be careful with the actual type of the fields you're fetching.  [Here's a list](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/cimwin32prov/win32-service) of properties for Win32_Service objects.